# Memory leak with Eigen sparse matrices multiplication

Tags: c++, memory-leaks, sparse-matrix, eigen

I have these three sparse matrices, defined in the following way:

```
typedef SparseMatrix<double> SpMat;

int m_totSize = 256*256;

SpMat *L = new SpMat(m_totSize, m_totSize);
SpMat *A = new SpMat(m_totSize, m_totSize);     
SpMat *W = new SpMat(m_totSize, m_totSize);
```

I am setting L with "setFromTriplets" and set W as the identity matrix.

Now I want to do:

```
*A = (*W)*(*L);
```

(Although I know it's going to give me L back).

And then:

```
delete L;
delete A;
delete W;
```

Even though I'm deleting the matrices at the end (I've also tried resize(0,0)), I'm experiencing severe memory leaks because of this multiplication.

Any ideas?

Thanks!

Comment: What OS are you on?

Comment: Windows 7, 64 bit

Comment: Are you sure the memory leak is in this part of your code? Does the memory leak still occur if you create a executable with only these lines of code?

Comment: I know it doesn't happen when I comment out the multiplication.

Answer (score 0):

It seems the memory leak originates from another part of my application, and the multiplication is the final straw (in terms of memory consumption). But it does not originate from there... sorry.